# Service to update WPF application placed on server

Tags: wpf, windows, wcf, service, auto-update

I am developing a WPF application, which will be accessed from shared folder on server (Windows Server). My goal is to implement some mechanism of updating the app. The updater should be run on server probably as some kind of service. Which mechanism/technique would you recommended to use?

Comment: What do you mean by updating the app? What exactly are you updating?

Comment: I want to replace the old version of application with new one, downloaded from from web server. (compare the files and download what was changed)

Comment: Clickonce is best for you...

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, I would look into using ClickOnce.

> ClickOnce enables Web-style application deployment for non-Web
>   applications. Applications are published to and deployed from Web or
>   file servers.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d(v=vs.140).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Squirrel.

> Squirrel: It's like ClickOnce but Works™

https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows